# Remove "Capture Video" button and give same functionality to the button outside popover controller

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I am creating an application in which i am using popover controller for opening a video camera. That control is givin a button which is used to start video recording. Now is it possible to remove that button and give same functionality to the button outside that popover controller?

Here is the code for opening video camera in popovercontroller

```
-(IBAction)openVideoCameraPopOver:(id)sender
{  
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
{
    @try 
    {
        if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {      

            UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];         
            NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];

            if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) 
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                                message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."                                                                       delegate:self 
                                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                                      otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
                return;
            }

            videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];           
            videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
            videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 120;
            videoRecorder.delegate = self;

            videoRecorder.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(25,25);       
            popoverCamera= [[UIPopoverController alloc]
            initWithContentViewController:videoRecorder];
            [popoverCamera presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.x,cropRectangleButton.frame.origin.y,0,0) inView:innerview permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];

            [self presentModalViewController:videoRecorder animated:YES];  
            [videoRecorder release];

        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) 
    {

    }

}
else
{
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Take picture " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Camera", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    actionSheet.alpha=0.90;
    actionSheet.tag = 1;
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view]; 
    [actionSheet release]; 
 }}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(IBAction)MyNewButton
{  
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {      

        UIImagePickerController *videoRecorder = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];         
        NSArray *sourceTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:videoRecorder.sourceType];

        if (![sourceTypes containsObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie] ) 
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil 
                                                            message:@"Device Not Supported for video Recording."                                                                       delegate:self 
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes" 
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"No",nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
            return;
        }

        videoRecorder.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        videoRecorder.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObject:(NSString*)kUTTypeMovie];           
        videoRecorder.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeLow;
        videoRecorder.videoMaximumDuration = 120;
        videoRecorder.delegate = self;

        videoRecorder.contentSizeForViewInPopover=CGSizeMake(25,25);       
        popoverCamera= [[UIPopoverController alloc]
        initWithContentViewController:videoRecorder];


        [self.view addsubview:videoRecorder.view];  
        [videoRecorder release];


}
```

Try this

Comment: What is ur actual requirement ?

Comment: Do you want Custom UIImagePicker ? is it?